# GNU `find` seems not work with -size to find the file whose size is less than *M

Tags: shell, find

I want to find the file whose size is less than 1M, so I write as `find . -size -1M`. But it seems not work indeed:

```
find . -size -1M | xargs ls -lh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xyz xyz 0 Apr  2 14:48 ./test/score
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xyz xyz 0 Apr  2 14:48 ./test/ir1
```

On the contrary, it's amazing that `find . -size 1M` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man find`:

> The  +  and  -  prefixes  signify greater than and less than, as
> usual; i.e., an exact size of n units does not match.   Bear  in mind
> that  the  size is rounded up to the next unit.  Therefore
> -size -1M is not equivalent to -size -1048576c.  The former only matches  empty  files,  the  latter  matches  files  from  0  to
> 1,048,575 bytes.

Comment: And where did you find this reference? I can't see such saying on https://linux.die.net/man/1/find.

Comment: It was taken out of `man find` on my Linux laptop (Linux Mint 20.3, find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0.  The page you referenced seems to be from 4.2.